# Faster alternative to eval(parse(text=...) taking string to variable in R

Tags: r, eval, dynamically-generated

I am not well versed in R.  I have read the other eval() posts on here, but none address my situation.  I  have a function that dynamically creates variables and uses `nlsLM` from the `minpack.lm` package to optimize.  It works, but it is slow (doing 100K iterations of this takes forever).  I need to dynamically be able to create variables for optimization in my function since the number of covariates in the design matrix X can change. So I use `eval(parse(text=...)` along with other dynamic code to address.  But, using `Rprof()` revealed that `eval(parse(text=...)` is taking up the majority of processing time. What is a faster alternative than `eval(parse(text=...)` that will enable me to dynamically create variables and work in `nlsLM`?  I have included a minimally reproducible example with a very simple linear regression model to illustrate (not my true non-linear model).

```
library(minpack.lm)
y<-c(-4.3, -4.3, -3.59, -2.75, -2.247,-2.227, -1.806, -0.536,  0.0275,0.20296,-0.274,-0.00772, 0.19189,-0.95812,-1.3587,-1.78749,-2.36696,-2.15504,-3.164070458,-3.830112052)
Cov1<-c(0,0,3.546704,5.263044,4.842031,3.180945,5.211059,4.774104, 2.696334,3.901650,3.641349,2.676252,4.338524,1.026670,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Cov2<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3.546704,5.263044,4.842031,3.180945,5.211059,4.774104, 2.696334,3.901650,3.641349,2.676252,4.338524,1.026670,0)
X<-cbind(INT=1,Cov1=Cov1,Cov2=Cov2)
nvar=NCOL(X)
p<-"c(b0"; for (i in 1:(nvar-1)) p=paste0(p,",b",i); p=paste0(p,")")
varnames<-c(paste0("b",0:(nvar-1)))
init<-structure(rep(0,nvar), .Names = varnames)
lb<-structure(c(rep(-Inf,nvar)), .Names = varnames)
ub<-structure(c(rep(Inf,nvar)), .Names = varnames)
parms <- nlsLM(y~X%*%eval(parse(text=p)),start=init, lower=lb,upper=ub)
```

Comment: You example is not reproducible: X is missing; which package is `nlsLM` from?

Comment: An why the complex code: what is wrong with `start = c(b0 = 0, b1 = 0, b2 = 0, r1 = 0, r = 0)`? And `p <- paste0("c(", paste0("b", 1:nvar - 1, collapse=","), ")")`?

Comment: @JanvanderLaan, Thanks for your comments.  Sorry, I posted the wrong code earlier.  I've edited my post to make it properly reproducible.  Also, it no longer has the hard-coded variable names (older code that was incorrectly posted).  I need my variables and names to be dynamically created based on the number of covariates in the design matrix X, which can change.